# Calling webservice with SSL context ends up with: PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore, mtls, sslcontext

I'm running Spring Boot application with some simple REST services. In one of them I need to make a request to external webservice, which requires TLS. Cert file and key file for TLS communication were obtained.

Cert file was added into new empty truststore (trust-store.jks). I also created new empty keystore (key-store.jks) and I imported keypair - the same cert file and key.

Key-store and trust-store were added into project resources folder.

Then, while calling external service I'm creating SSL context like this *(CustomConfig contains path to keystores on classpath and passwords)*:

```
public SslContext createSslContext(CustomConfig customConfig) {
    try {
          
      var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      try (var keyStoreStream = new ClassPathResource(customConfig.getKeyStore().getStore()).getInputStream()) {
        keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, customConfig.getKeyStore().getPassword().toCharArray());
      }

      var keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, customConfig.getKeyStore().getPassword().toCharArray());

      var trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      try (var trustStoreStream = new ClassPathResource(customConfig.getTrustStore().getStore()).getInputStream()) {
        trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, customConfig.getTrustStore().getPassword().toCharArray());
      }

      var trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

      return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
          .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
          .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
          .build();
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
      throw new SslContextException("Failed to create SSL context: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

SSL context is built without any issue, but while http client trying to create connection this error occures:

> Error: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Obtained cert and key file are valid, and I'm able to call external webservice with *curl* and those files.

Any suggestions, what I'm missing here?

Comment: You're not totally clear but it sounds like you put the client cert in the truststore. That's backwards. The truststore must contain a validation anchor -- usually a root CA cert -- _for the server, not the client_. If the server cert is from a 'well-known' CA, that root is likely already in Java's default truststore. If curl accepts the server cert without specifying --cacert (or --insecure/-k) then the CA for the server is in curl's default truststore, which is not always identical to Java's default but is usually close.